# Thymeleaf. Why each html file have sections: html, head, body?

Tags: thymeleaf

I was wondering Why Thymeleaf always have same tags like:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

In each file with template html?

Answer (score 1):

That's the standard structure for an HTML file. Everything goes inside these tags.

Comment: So I should follow this standard? What about css and js files? Should I added it to main Layout.html, or to each html file?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you add them to the layout they'll be on every page, so that's another decision you have to make.

Comment: I would like to not repeat the html elements like head or footer. I would like to use some templating library. In thymeleaf in each tutorial every where is <head>, but I dont wonna follow this way. Here is example: http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com/2014/01/spring-mvc-with-thymeleaf-html-template.html

Comment: layout.htm is going to include other files, that's what a templating engine is for among other things. If you have a general page that includes others based on url you don't need to repeat the  components on every page.